# How to test iOS purchases in developer environment?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to install app on my device from my workstation and test in app purchases on development environment and not on sandbox environment? Everytime I try it, it takes me to sandbox environment.

How is iOS distinguishing whether purchases must run in sandbox environment or on production environment? I want to do a end to end testing like how it would be for regular users?

I currently have an issue where payments are working from my Sandbox environment but not on production? What could be the issue? Is there any latency for my in-app purchase items to be  available on app store kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what you mean by "*on development environment and not on sandbox environment*".
In-App Purchase Sandbox is for development purposes.

iOS distinguishes between sandbox and production environments using code-sign. 
If you are code-signing with iPhone Developer profile, you are in the sandbox environment. And if you are using iPhone Distribution profile, you are in the production environment.

Yes, App Store servers have some delay. It takes some time your In-App Purchase to be activated. You might get "*No Product Found*" error for a while. It is just like Game-Center, as you can't see your leaderboards for a while when your app is just gone live.

Comment: This was the exact issue. It took some time for apple to update its servers with proper product ids. Knowing very little less about the whole flow, it created a panic among us. But now it seems to be working everywhere and working great :)